# How can I map to copy last selection to the clipboard?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I often find myself doing `gv"+y` to copy the last selection to the clipboard. How can I map this to the key combination `[p` ?

EDIT: how can I restore the cursor to the original spot? Or alternatively, I would not like the cursor to move when I run the shortcut.

Comment: Depending on WHY you do this, there may be other solutions as well, mostly involving the use of the 'clipboard' option. You should take a look at that also.

Comment: @Ben I do this to paste into an external application. I do not like their built-in editor so I write my files in R. Often times I make little edits and want to re-run the code.

Comment: @mtadd Thanks, do you happen to know how I can make it so the cursor does not move when running the shortcut?

Comment: Sure, just add a mark to the beginning, and a jump to the end, e.g. nnoremap [p mngv"+y`n

Comment: @mtadd thanks, that helps. I'm not sure if I want to overwrite the 'n' marker though (or any other one for that matter). Is there a better way? Also, can you add this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is so trivial that I won't spell it out for you. The general syntax is

```
:nnoremap {lhs} {rhs}
```

To keep the cursor position, just re-enter visual mode with `gv` once again. That will restore the cursor position. If you don't want to stay in visual mode, append `<Esc>`. If you always create the selection from front to end, or want the cursor always positioned at the start of the selection, `` g`< `` would be a shorter alternative.